# Cannot compile javascript files in NetBeans using Rhino

Tags: javascript, netbeans, rhino

My goal is to create a project (don't know yet if it has to be html5 or java project) in netbeans, add js file with any line of code and then press compile it and run.

I wuld like to have my js files compile to *.class files as it can be done via js console according to rhino tutorial on mozilla page.

But as i said i would like to have it via pressing run/compile button in my netbeans

Currently i'm using netbeans 7.3(i'm honestly open to change version if necesarry) and windows

I already try to do many things but only 2 are worth describing:
  -edit build.xml file to use js.jar from rhino
  -just run java project with javascript files - according to some articles it should be possible but in my case in just left js files uncompiled

Please help
Aleksandra